# school library sql schema - list loans by school

Tags: sql

I am working on a prototype library for schools.
Relations is: "school" have many "books" and book have many loans.
My question: i want to list all loans for specific school. Should have a reference to the school in table "loan"?
My intention is to use java with eclipselink.
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want us to do your homework for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: have you tried any tutorial for many to many mappings in orm's?

Comment: your question is that you want to list all loans for specific school ... In order for me to answer that I'll ask you this, does a book belong to one and only one school or it may belongs to many schools ?

if it does belong to one and only one school then you can grab all books IDs of a school and use a `WHERE IN` clause in your SQL to fetch all loans that have a book_id in the IDs you previously fetched

Comment: same book can exist in different school with different inventory number.

Answer (score 0):

In a relational database the answer would be no. The query would be to link loans, to books and then school and then school, and filter on school.

I suspect that you may want to show more than just a book Id (e.g. title) in your query, so you would have to link to the books table at some point.

Answer (score 0):

My believe is that there should be such an additional links between the loan and the school. But i want to be sure. How would a prototype query in these conditions? An example using entities will be better for me?
Will be something like this?

`Select from Loan where Loan.Book.School == School`